# AngularJS: Reverse Checkbox State

Tags: angularjs

Somehow, through the magic of Angular, if you use `ng-model` and provide it a boolean, your checkbox will be checked if said boolean is true, and unchecked if false.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="video.hidden">
```

While this alone is fairly baffling, I'm actually trying to reverse the checked state, because unlike the todo example where `todo.done` means the box gets checked, my model is more like `todo.incomplete`.

Unfortunately my first guess didn't work:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="!video.hidden">
```

I'm in a position where the model has been dictated to me, so I can't change it and don't want to have to massage it on the client (because I'm sending client objects back to the server, since it's running in a trusted environment).

**Update**

This works in 1.3 and doesn't give you strings (1.2.xxx gave you strings instead of booleans):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="video.hidden" ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true">
```

Comment: or just use a negation of whatever word you used to describe your model : video.shown : ? or use a function in your controller to set the value of another model when the checkbox is checked ... it is not a real problem in my opinion.

Comment: @camus The last thing I said was that I did not want to change the model, and I shouldn't have to. Of course it's not a real problem, but when a framework is touting ease of use, there's no reason why my first guess above shouldn't work.

Comment: using a function is not changing the model but adding a function to a controller. And no framework is a silver bullet. But this one is easily extentable , that's what you'll have to do anyway , write directives.

Comment: Your "ng-true-value" fix that you say "doesn't work right now" seems to work with the current angular code: http://plnkr.co/edit/tmpdYBiuzv9cy8JfRWtw?p=preview... Or am I misunderstanding what was broken with that?

Comment: @Troy It looks like it works in 1.3.6, but still does not work correctly in 1.2.27 (you get strings instead of booleans).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can make that now without a need of custom directive, angular support `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[checkbox]

your example should work now
`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="video.hidden" ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true">`

Comment: Problem with that solution is that the checkbox will still display the video.hidden value when displayed.

Comment: Looks like they fixed it in 1.3.

Comment: I see `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`, but the `false` value is not sent to the server. Maybe it's treated as not successful form control.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati , try adding `value="true"` ?

Comment: to do this in Angular Material - can refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693740/setting-check-value-to-inverse-value

Answer (score 23):

I don't think there's a way to do this purely in the template. The most obvious way to accomplish this is create a new scope variable that's manually double-bound to your model value. So like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="videoShowing">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.videoShowing = !$scope.video.hidden;

$scope.$watch('video.hidden', function(value) {
  $scope.videoShowing = !value;
});
$scope.$watch('videoShowing', function(value) {
  $scope.video.hidden = !value;
}
```

You could almost just use one-way binding with an ng-change, but that doesn't quite work:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="!video.hidden" ng-change="???">
```

Because ng-change doesn't mix the current value into the local scope at all. If you were in a context where you had access to the NgModelController you could do something, but you'd need a custom directive for that. Wouldn't be hard to make an "inverted" attribute directive that modifies the NgModel's formatters and parsers. I'd suggest that if you need lots of inverted checkboxes.

**Edit**

For posterity, making an "inverted" attribute is super simple, might as well just do that. Making directives always seems like a pain at first, but it really is the Angular way.

```
someModule.directive('inverted', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) { return !val; });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) { return !val; });
    }
  };
});
```

Might need to set the priority too, or "unshift" instead of push, to make sure these guys run after the built-in inputDirective ones.

Comment: what is `ngModel` argument here? is there any documentation about it? or it is a some type of DI magic?

Comment: The 4th argument to `link` mirrors whatever you `require`.

Answer (score 14):

This seems to work

```
<input  type="checkbox" 
        ng-init = "video.checked = !video.hidden"
        ng-model ="video.checked"
        ng-change ="video.hidden = !video.checked"/>
```

It introduces a `video.checked` property that's the opposite of `video.hidden` and as soon as the checkbox changes the values are updated.

Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7HYht6ubkUUJQ0r3g16m?p=preview

Comment: Nice, this appears to work. Is the `ng-init` part necessary though? Inside of `ng-change`, do you not have access to the `input` read the checked state from it?

Comment: without `ng-init` when the view is compiled the value of `video.checked` would be `undefined` and checkboxes would be unchecked even when `video.hidden` is set to `false` which is when you want them checked. If you remove `ng-init` you would need to modify your `videos` objects from the controller and do the initialization from there.

Comment: So you don't have access to the target `input` inside of ng-change?  Like, I couldn't say: `ng-change ="video.hidden = !$element.checked"`

Comment: One issue, which may not be a problem in your use case, is that the video.checked will not get updated automatically if the video.hidden changes programmatically.  The solution by darkporter below is more robust.

Comment: good point. I'd personally write a custom directive and let it worry about updating the checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

My solution uses a directive "negate", that you just add to the "input".
It's simple, and there is no need to change the controller.

```
angular
    .module("<< your module >>")
    .directive('negate', [
        function () {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attribute, ngModelController) {
                    ngModelController.$isEmpty = function(value) {
                        return !!value;
                    };

                    ngModelController.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                        return !value;
                    });

                    ngModelController.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                        return !value;
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

Use it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" negate ng-model="entity.nologin">
```

Answer (score 2):

My Solution is Very simple: Just use **ng-true-value** / **ng-false-value** and set false to ng-true-value and true to ng-false-value which will reverse the functionality.

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="<<-- Your Model -->> " ng-true-value="false"
            ng-false-value="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution to get the checked or unchecked value for a checkbox is by adding the ng-init directive inside the checkbox input element as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="video = false" ng-model="video" >
```

This enables the initial value of the checkbox to be false, were the state is unchecked. On submitting the form, if the checkbox is unchecked the value that returns (or console) will be false, instead of 'undefined', else upon checking it will be true.

if you want to add custom made values for the true or false state, you can use:

```
ng-true-value="'custom_true value'"
```

and

```
ng-false-value="'custom_false value'"
```

inside the input element.
like :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="video = false" ng-model="video" ng-true-value="'custom_true value'" ng-false-value="'custom_false value'">
```