# Filtering with multiple checkboxes in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS. I wrote a program to filter the Item list when i check related check boxes. But here my CheckBoxes are behaving like "Radio" buttons. Anyway, program is working but it is not working with multiple check boxes. Please help me.

My Program @ http://plnkr.co/edit/iV7wyYoCNJdY1Ze7J6Pg?p=preview

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Easy way

I would Set different models for both check boxes and add filter like:

```
<body data-ng-controller="TestController">
        <table id="hotels">
            <tr>
                <th>Hotel Name</th>
                <th>Star Rating</th>
                <th>Hotel type</th>
                <th>Hotel Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="hotel in hotels | filter:search.type1 | filter:search.type2">
                <td>{{hotel.name}}</td>
                <td>{{hotel.star}}</td>
                <td>{{hotel.type}}</td>
                <td>{{hotel.price}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <h4>Filters</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='search.type1' data-ng-true-value='luxury' data-ng-false-value='' /> Luxury &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='search.type2' data-ng-true-value='double suite' data-ng-false-value='' /> Double suite
    </body>
```

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5WF6FxvwocVBqhuvt4VL?p=preview)</kbd>

### Custom filter##

(<sub>I like it more</sub>)

We can bind  the checkboxes to one object like:

```
$scope.types = {luxury: false, double_suite:false};
```

and after create custom filter like:

```
iApp.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, types) {
    var filtered = [];
    
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
       if(types.luxury == false && types.double_suite == false) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }
        else if(types.luxury == true && types.double_suite == false && item.type == 'luxury'){
          filtered.push(item);
        }
        else if(types.double_suite == true && types.luxury == false && item.type == 'double suite'){
          filtered.push(item);
        }
    });
  
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

So our HTML now seems simple:

```
 <body data-ng-controller="TestController">
        <table id="hotels">
            <tr>
                <th>Hotel Name</th>
                <th>Star Rating</th>
                <th>Hotel type</th>
                <th>Hotel Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="hotel in hotels |  myfilter:types">
                <td>{{hotel.name}}</td>
                <td>{{hotel.star}}</td>
                <td>{{hotel.type}}</td>
                <td>{{hotel.price}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <h4>Filters</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='types.luxury'  /> Luxury &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='types.double_suite'  /> Double suite
        <pre>{{types|json}}</pre>
    </body>
```

Demo 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b0LMJzUiJy0NO9Hk0oWt?p=preview)</kbd>

**[EDIT for @Mike]**

If you interesting to invert the check-box filter, just add directive (grabbed from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925462/angularjs-reverse-checkbox-state)):

```
iApp.directive('inverted', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) { return !val; });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) { return !val; });
    }
  };
});
```

sow new HTML form:

```
 <input type="checkbox" inverted data-ng-model='types.luxury'  /> Luxury &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" inverted data-ng-model='types.double_suite'  /> Double suite
```

Demo 3 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5R7dIDjCp3hWVGvEI8i?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Tnx. Can we generate these models dynamically?

Comment: @MaximShoustin: how can it be made that so on selection of checkboxes the values display? and not otherwise

Comment: @MaximShoustin none of these examples work as expected with both of the check boxes de/selected

Comment: @chrisFrisina witch browser do you use? i run Chrome, works as expected

Comment: @MaximShoustin Chrome v 35.0.1916.114   No errors either in the console, even scoped to the plinker and not to the general page.

Comment: @chrisFrisina really strange, tested in chrome and firefox. when both checkboxes un/selected we get full or empty list

Comment: Easy way return ERROR: "Expected constant expression for `ngTrueValue`"

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin : In case of inverted can we make it like instead of show values of unchecked box, we can show values of selected checkbox.

For example like : 1) Bydefault all 3 checkboxes will checked. 2) If any one unchecked that records belong to that checkbox will get hide.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me you are not really familiar with custom filter and prefer a simpler solution, here is a simple example to bind data with ng-model of checkboxes in ng-repeat: [tutorial here](http://webtoutsaint.com/multiple_checkboxes)

It is a good example with ng-value-true and ng-value-false :

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits"> 
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.name" ng-true-value="{{fruit.name}}" ng-false-value="{{fruit-name}} - unchecked" ng-change="filterMultipleSystem()"/><br/> 
</div>
```

The Javscript function:

```
 $scope.filterMultipleSystem = function(){ 
    setTimeout(function () { 
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("firstLoop"); 
    var i; for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 

    if(x[i].title.indexOf("unchecked")!==-1){ 
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    } 

    else 
    x[i].style.display = "inherit"; }},10); }`;
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Please include the source to `filterMultipleSystem`, which is not built into Angular.

Comment: @Chris I have already put the link to a tutorial where this function is inside http://webtoutsaint.com/multiple_checkboxes . But I 'll edit my post with the function

Comment: I know that the information is in the site you linked, but Stack Overflow [discourages link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Thanks for updating your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is bit refined filter(edited for my needs from @Maxim Shoustin) where you can select by multiple arguments. If u had 3 types and needed select 2 of 3, you can use this, cause other doesnt work on that(tried myself):

```
    app.filter('myfilter', function () {
    return function (items, types) {
        var filtered = [];
        for (var i in items)
        {

            if (types.found == true && items[i].type == 'Found') {
                filtered.push(items[i]);
            }                
            else if (types.notfound == true && items[i].type == 'Not found') {
                filtered.push(items[i]);
            }
            else if (types.moved == true && items[i].type == 'Moved') {
                filtered.push(items[i]);
            }
        }

        return filtered;
    };
});
```