# Setting check value to inverse value

Tags: angular, angular6

I am binding a list of checkboxes to an object like so:

```
<div class="column-option" *ngFor="let col of columnState; index as i;">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="!columnState[i].hide">{{col.colId}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

This displays fine but when checking the checkbox it doesn't inverse the boolean value.

If I change `[(ngModel)]="!columnState[i].hide"` to `[(ngModel)]="columnState[i].hide"` then the model is updated but I want the logic of `hide=false` to have the checkbox ticked.

How can I inverse the displayed checked value so when someone unchecks the checkbox the model will be `hide=true`?

edit:

The docs for checkbox (https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) say:

> When user clicks on the mat-checkbox, the default behavior is toggle checked value and set indeterminate to false. This behavior can be customized by providing a new value of MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION to the checkbox.

and then shows this being set as an array but it doesn't show how to actually inject this value which is confusing.  I tried binding to `(click)` but it didn't work.  It seems I need to disable default click handler with injection so my click handler will work.

How do I set a custom click action so I can inverse the value?

Comment: What's in columnState?

Comment: It is an object array with my grids columns state.  The `hide` property dictates whether to show column.  The grid is powered by third party library.

Comment: I mean it contains checked or true?can you  just give sample of this object

Comment: a boolean value true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to inject the value from documentation into the components decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-columns',
  templateUrl: './edit-columns.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-columns.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION, useValue: 'noop'}
  ]
})
```

`noop` disables default click so then I could make this method:

```
  toggleHiddenState(index: number)
  {
    this.columnState[index].hide = !this.columnState[index].hide;
  }
```

and then update my control like so:

```
  <div class="column-option" *ngFor="let col of columnState; index as i;">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="toggleHiddenState(i)" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="!columnState[i].hide">{{col.colId}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use ternary operator inside ngmodel value like this "isSpecial ? 3 : 1"

Comment: can view updated Angular docs from here https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview#click-action-config as MAT_CHECKBOX_CLICK_ACTION is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

basically you need Angular attribute on the matchbox element like "ng-click" to bind a controller function which changes the columnState[$index].hide value.

Comment: are you referring to AngularJS?  I think click handler has to be injected in mat checkbox but the docs don't give a clear example

Comment: Could you please provide more detail and example perhaps?